# jotform and jquery ticker control

Tags: jquery, compatibility, jotform

whenever i use jotform and jquery ticker controls, i am getting script errors. is there a compatibility issues between these two javascript libraries.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a script compatibility issue between Jquery and Jotform script (protoplus) .

http://www.jotform.com/answers/8649-Protoplus-Conflict